Using win.setContentProtection; to hide app from other apps (not working) but does flicker?
I'm building an app and packaging it up for MacOS. I'm using this code: win.setContentProtection (link to docs) to prevent the window contents from being captured by other apps.
However, when I share my screen with another person the app is visible (but flickers every few seconds) and I can't for the life of me figure out why.
I'd very much appreciate help from anyone who has experience with this part of Electron.
Thank you!
const path = require('path');

function createWindow() {
  const win = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true,
      contextIsolation: false,
    },
  });

  // Load the HTML file into the window
  win.loadFile(path.join(__dirname, 'index.html'));

  // Ensure the window is ready before applying content protection
  win.once('ready-to-show', () => {
    win.setContentProtection(true); // Set content protection
    win.show(); // Show the window after applying protection
    // Trigger screen capture sources to request screen recording permission
    getScreenSources();
  });
}

// Function to trigger the screen recording permission prompt
async function getScreenSources() {
  try {
    const sources = await desktopCapturer.getSources({ types: ['screen'] });
    console.log('Screen sources:', sources);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error getting screen sources:', error);
  }
}

app.whenReady().then(createWindow);

app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
    app.quit();
  }
});

app.on('activate', () => {
  if (BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) {
    createWindow();
  }
});


My research tells me that setContentProtection(true) in Electron doesn't reliably stop screen capture because many tools like Google Meet and Zoom's web client use newer screen capture methods that ignore this setting.
Electron can't fully control how all apps capture screens, and current workarounds don’t consistently work. So, there’s no guaranteed fix for this issue in Electron right now.
I'm trying to figure out if I should try native Electron plugins or move to Swift/Obj-C for more reliability. Does anyone have any ideas?
